# Certbot Letsencrypt install on local Wampserver

Tags: ssl, wamp, lets-encrypt, certbot

I hope somebody can help me with this problem. I am trying to install a SSL certificate on my local Wampserver of a dev.xyz.xy domain using webroot.

Command: certbot certonly --webroot C:\wamp64\www\xxx -d dev.xyz.xy

The http challenge verification is not working because the sever is not accessible form the internet. Can somebody please tell me if there is an option to use http anyway? If that is not possible what is the best way to verify?

Thank you very much for your answer.

Best, Gregor